# Java search program

Tags: java, search

I am trying to make this program that prints out the words that start with a certain letter from a list words. For example if you enter the letter "e" it should only print words that start with the letter "e" but for some reason it is reading words like "far east" even though it does not start with the letter "e". Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class words {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        File wordfile = new File("wrds.txt");
        if(wordfile.exists()){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(wordfile);
            int counter = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter a character");
            char wrd = key.next().charAt(0);
            while(keyboard.hasNext()) {
                String word = keyboard.next();
                if(word.startsWith(""+ wrd)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Found "+counter+" words that begin with "+ wrd);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, scanner breaks words with whitespaces. So 'far east' is scanned as 'far' and 'east'. Use delimiter instead to ignore whitespaces. Refer the code below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Words {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        File wordfile = new File("wrds.txt");
        if(wordfile.exists()){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(wordfile);
            int counter = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter a charycter");
            char wrd = key.next().charAt(0);
            keyboard.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            while(keyboard.hasNext()) {
                String word = keyboard.next();
                if(word.startsWith(""+ wrd)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Found "+counter+" words that begin with "+ wrd);
        }
    }
}
```